# Why ML models installed with pip need to download something else after installation?

Tags: python, docker, pip, bert-language-model

Why does this statement download the model? Why isn't it downloaded when I install the package with `pip3 install keybert`? How can I pre-load it to the docker image so it wouldn't be downloaded every time?

```
from keybert import KeyBERT
kw_model = KeyBERT()
```

Right now my dockerfile does the following:

```
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt
```

requirements.txt:

```
google-cloud-pubsub==2.8.0
google-cloud-logging==2.6.0
requests==2.28.0
keybert==0.5.1
```

Comment: Can you provide requirements.txt ? Checking here you are not missing keybert :)

Comment: Can you try to run `RUN pip show keybert` right after to see location ?

Comment: Whitout more context I would try to use option `-t` to install them to a controlled directory instead of `--user` which only ensure to not install it in OS packages [doc here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-t)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution is

1. Run this code on your local computer to save a copy of the model to a local directory. e.g. save to a directory "keybert"

```
from keybert import KeyBERT
kw_model = KeyBERT()
kw_model.model.embedding_model.save("keybert")
```

2. Add the local copy of the model to the Docker image using the `COPY` command in the Dockerfile

```
# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY ./keybert/ ./keybert/
```

3. In your script running in the Docker container, load the model from the directory

```
from keybert import KeyBERT
new_kw_model = KeyBERT("./keybert")
```

The reason for this behavior is that `KeyBERT` uses other SBERT models, and you can use KeyBERT with more than one model: https://maartengr.github.io/KeyBERT/guides/embeddings.html

So you'd add a copy of whichever model best suits your purposes to the Docker image